# error in DHT11 senosor reading values

Tags: proteus, arduino-uno

[image][image: aaa]

Hello guys,
I'm creating automatic mini greenhouse using Arduino Uno board on proteus. After compiling the code on Arduino no errors appeared, but after applying the code on proteus with the creation of the circuit as shown in the attachment(adding leds,lcd,dht11 sensor,moisture sensor,ldr sensor,servo motor,relay) the proteus gives some errors related to dht11 sensor, in which I had realized that dht11 sensor is not reading the values of temperature and humidity, so can someone explain it to me and tell me how can i solve it
Regards,

```
#include "DHT.h"             //for temperature and humidity sensor
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>   //for LCD display
#include <Servo.h>           //for servo motor
Servo myservo;
 int pos = 0;
 #define DHTPIN 8       // anaolg pin 22
 #define DHTTYPE DHT11 
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);  //pins connected for LCD
int LDR = A2;                   //select the input pin for LDR
int LDRValue = 0;              //variable to store the value coming from the sensor
int light_sensitivity = 300;
 void setup()
 { 
Serial.begin(9600);  
lcd.begin(16, 2);                  //set up the LCD's number of columns and rows
lcd.print("Reading sensor");       //Print a message to the LCD
dht.begin(); 
myservo.attach(9);                 //servo motor connected to pin 9
pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
delay(400);
 } 
void loop() 
{ 
LDRValue = analogRead(LDR);       //read the value from the sensor
Serial.println(LDRValue); 
delay(50); 
if (LDRValue < light_sensitivity)
 {
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
delay(100);
 }
 else  
{
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);
 delay(400);
 }
float humi = dht.readHumidity();           //read temperature as celsius
 float temp = dht.readTemperature();    //read temp as fahrenheit
 delay(200);
 lcd.clear();
 char tempF[6];
 char humF[6];
 dtostrf(temp, 5, 1, tempF);  // we use the dtostrf function to convert our temperature and humidity value from type float to string and then we print it on the LCD
 dtostrf(humi, 2, 0, humF);
 lcd.print("T:"); 
lcd.print(tempF);
 lcd.print((char)223);    // Note that the explicit typecasting used in the lcd.print() function ((char)223) is used to print the degree symbol on the display.
 lcd.print("C ");
 lcd.print("H: ");
 lcd.print(humF);
 lcd.print("%");          //the solution on screen is < T:24.0*C     H:40%>
 if (temp < 22)
 { 
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
delay(100);
  }
 else
 {
 digitalWrite(7,LOW);
 delay(400);
 }
 if (temp >28)
 {
 digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  delay(100);
 }
 else
 {
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
 delay(400);
 }
 if (humi < 50)
 {
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  delay(100);
 }
 else
 { 
 digitalWrite(7,LOW);
delay(400);
 }
 if (humi > 60)
 {
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  delay(100);
 }
 else 
{ 
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
 delay(400);
 }
 lcd.clear();
 int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);     //sensorValue is moisture sensor connected to pin A0
 Serial.println(sensorValue);
if(sensorValue<400)
{
lcd.print("Soil Type:Dry");
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);           //set the cursor to column 0, line 1
                              // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
lcd.print("Level: 80~99%");
delay(100);
 digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
for(pos=0;pos<=180;pos+=1)           //command to move from 0 degree to 180 degree
{
   //water pump on 
myservo.write(pos);               //command to rotate the servo to the specified angle
delay(15);
}
 lcd.clear();
 delay(2000);
 }
if((sensorValue>400)&&( (sensorValue<600)))
{
lcd.print("Soil Type:Humid ");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Level: 45~65%");
 delay(100);
 for(pos = 180; pos>=0; pos-=1)   //command to move from 180 to 0
{
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
 myservo.write(pos);
 delay(15);
 }
 lcd.clear();
delay(2000);
 }
 if((sensorValue>600)&&( sensorValue<950))
{
  digitalWrite(7,LOW); 
//water pump off
 lcd.print("Soil Type:Watery");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Level: 0~5%");
 delay(1000);
 lcd.clear();
 delay(2000);
 }
 }
```

Comment: hi. 1. Format your code. There's a button for doing that in the **question editor**. 2. what is your **precise question**?

Comment: 1. I can't find question editor to format my code, I made  auto format. 2. the dht11 sensor can't read values, in which the error they told me that model DHTXXITF is specified but not found in U1_#P, so how can i solve this problem?@MarcusMüller

Comment: 1. Click the "edit" link below your question. In the editor, select the text you wish to format as code. Click the `{ }` symbol in the top bar. 2. You have to ask a question that is answerable, giving al relevant information but most importantly what you expected to happen and what actually happens, including any error messages. 3. If you wish to add additional information later, *add it to the question* and not in a comment.